# vb.net MCE Remote Button Detection

Tags: vb.net, windows-mce

I am currently using the following function to detect special button presses (Play, Stop, Pause) on my MCE remote.

```
    Private Const WM_APPCOMMAND As Integer = &H319

Public Function WndProc(hwnd As IntPtr, msg As Integer, wParam As IntPtr, lParam As IntPtr, ByRef handled As Boolean) As IntPtr
    If msg = WM_APPCOMMAND Then
        Dim cmd As Integer = CInt(CUInt(lParam) >> 16 And Not &HF000)
        Select Case cmd
            Case 13 'Stop

        'Some Code

                Exit Select
            Case 47 'Pause

                 'Some Code

                Exit Select
            Case 46 'Play

                    'Some Code

                Exit Select
        End Select

        handled = True
    End If

    Return IntPtr.Zero
End Function
```

I would also like the functionality of using the colored buttons as well however when they are pressed, they do not seem to return anything for cmd.

Is there a way i can achieve this functionality?

Comment: Are you sure they don't return anything? Try `Case Else Debug.print(cmd)`

Comment: I am sure, i did messagebox.show(cmd) before the select

Comment: http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=114510 / http://superuser.com/questions/11347/media-center-remote-control-how-can-i-configure-the-4-colors-buttons - seem to indicate this is tricky!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These buttons can't be intercepted using the normal techniques (low level system hooks), but can be detected using RegisterRawInputDevices and looking for RAWINPUT Windows Messages.  (RAWINPUT 91=Red, 92=Green, 93=Yellow, 94=Blue).

Comment: Would you mind giving me an example? i am having trouble finding documentation on RegisterRawInputDevices

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996387.aspx - c# but easily translatable. Furthers docs here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645600.aspx